# Research into storage and uploading sites

Tags: mobile-application, mobile-web, uploading

In regards to researching, I have come across something a bit tricky (as in, I'm not satisfied with the research I have found).

I'm talking about sites and apps that specialise in storage and uploading. Think of your Dropboxes, Box.com, Google Drive and even the cloud drives out there. I cannot seem to find any reports into user findings or any best practices. All I got is opinionated blogs and Pinterest boards!

No doubt I am missing a great source out there. If there is any recommendations on where to look, that would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Dan

Comment: Possible for you to share your findings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most companies like that likely do not share their user research and keep it internal for a competitive advantage. If you have any particular questions about storage and uploading best practices, **you should be able to search the academic literature.**

For example, if you are curious about public attitudes towards privacy as it relates to cloud storage, [here's an ACM paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2078845) discussing it. Just use Google Scholar to find the particular topic you're wondering about.